# How to Switch Between Panels whitch Buttons

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

I can not navigate between the panels of my App through the buttons. I followed a lot of tutorials like [this one](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/16/wxpython-how-to-switch-between-panels/) but none solve my problem.
Thank for Help.

```
####################-----Principal Panel (first Panel)
    import wx
    from OtherPanel import OtherPanel
    class MyPanel(wx.Panel):  
        def __init__(self, parent):
            """Constructor"""
            wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent = parent, size=(600, 500))

            self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(250, 250, 250))
            parent.Center()
            self.histoPanel = OtherPanel(self)
            self.home()
            self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        def home(self):
            self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
            self.panel.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(250, 250, 250))
            bS =wx.Button(self, -1,"Go some where ",(200,30), size=(150,150))
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.Sy, bS)
            bOthe = wx.Button(self, -1,"Go to OtherPanel",(400,30),(150,150))
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onOpenFrame,bOthe)
        def onOpenFrame(self, event):
            """
            Opens secondary frame
            """
            self.Hide()
            self.histoPanel.Show()

        def Sy(self, event):
            """
            I have another panel (panel 3)
            """
            self.Hide()
            #self.panel3.Show()
```

--Second Panel (another Panel)
this panel is displayed when you click on the button of the first panel

```
    import wx

    class OtherPanel(wx.Panel):

        def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
            wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent = parent)
            self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
            self.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(250, 250, 250))
            self.Center()
            self.homeHist()
            self.Show()
        def homeHist(self):
            bBack = wx.Button(self, -1, "", pos=(20,30), size=(50,50))
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onClose, bBack)

        def onClose(self, event):
            self.Close()
```

------My Frame---.
here is my Frame/Windows. he must wear all the panels in turn

```
    import wx
    from MyPanel import MyPanel
    from OtherPanel import OtherPanel

    class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
        """"""
        def __init__(self):
            """Constructor"""
            wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, size = (600,500))
            self.myPanel = MyPanel(self)
            self.otherpanel = OtherPanel(self)
            self.otherpanel.Hide()
            self.menu()

            self.CreateStatusBar(style= wx.BORDER_NONE)
            self.SetBackgroundColour("gray")
            self.SetStatusText("\tthank")


        def menu(self):

            menubar = wx.MenuBar()
            fileMenu = wx.Menu()
            menubar.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(1, 1, 6))

            fileMenu.AppendSeparator()
            live = wx.MenuItem(fileMenu, wx.ID_EXIT, '&Quit\tCtrl+Q', '\tlive my app')
            fileMenu.Append(live)
            self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.Onexit, live)

            menubar.Append(fileMenu, '\t&Menu')
            self.SetMenuBar(menubar)

        def Onexit(self, event):
            self.Close(True)

        def Bouton(self, event):
            if self.myPanel.IsShown():
                self.SetTitle("Panel Two Showing")
                self.myPanel.Hide()
                self.otherpanel.Show()
            else:
                self.SetTitle("Panel One Showing")
                self.myPanel.Show()
                self.otherpanel.Hide()
            self.Layout()

        if __name__ == "__main__":
            app = wx.App(False)
            frame = MyFrame()
            frame.Show()
            app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `MyPanel.__init__` you are creating an instance of `OtherPanel` assigned to `self.histoPanel` as a child of the `MyPanel`, and then `MyPanel's` event handlers are hiding itself, which in turn hides its children including the `self.histoPanel`. You're also creating some panels assigned to `self.panel` which don't seem to be used for anything.

The way you are doing it in the `MyFrame` class is much better. It creates both panels and hides one. Then in `MyFrame.Bouton` it hides one and shows the other, depending on the current state. So what you need to do is get rid of all the extra panels in `MyPanel` (`self.histoPanel` and also the various `self.panels` that are never used for anything) and then you just need to have the button event ask the parent frame to swap the panels instead of trying to do it itself.

Comment: Thank's @RbinDunn for your reply. I got rid of `MyPanel (self.histoPanel` and `self.panels`.In `OtherPanel` I added `size=(600, 500)`.now I do not know how to ask  the button event of the parent frame to swap the panels instead of trying to do it itself.I want to point out that this is my very first project witch `wxpython`. And i use `python 3.5.2`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what Robin is suggesting in his answer:

```
import wx

class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.btn = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Panel 1", size=(250,75))
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.switch)

        vbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox1.Add(self.btn)
        self.panel.SetSizer(vbox1)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(self.panel)
        self.SetSizer(vbox)

        self.Show()

    def switch(self, event):
        self.parent.Swap()

class MyOtherPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.btn = wx.Button(self.panel, label="Panel 2", size=(175,250))
        self.btn.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.switch)

        vbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox1.Add(self.btn)
        self.panel.SetSizer(vbox1)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        vbox.Add(self.panel)
        self.SetSizer(vbox)

        self.Show()
        self.panel.Hide()

    def switch(self, event):
        self.parent.Swap()

class PanelSwitcher(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(None)

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.panel1 = MyPanel(self)
        self.panel2 = MyOtherPanel(self)
        vbox.Add(self.panel1)
        vbox.Add(self.panel2)
        self.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.Show()

    def Swap(self):
        if self.panel1.panel.IsShown():
            self.panel1.panel.Hide()
            self.panel2.panel.Show()
        else:
            self.panel2.panel.Hide()
            self.panel1.panel.Show()
        self.Layout()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    PanelSwitcher()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: thank you all. I could solve the problem under `Linux` (there was not even one). but under `Windows (10)` there is supperposition of the `Widget` of the first `Panel` and that of the second `Panel` when I navigate from the first to the second. I use `Python 3.5.2` and `wxpython 4`

Comment: I could not solve my problem under `Windows`. I'm going to get rid of the `Linus version`. thank you to everyone who helped me